# How to Remove a portion of the canvas from square customview android?

Tags: android, canvas, background, android-custom-view, transparent

[image]I had been trying to draw an arc with color filled on top of the arc and removing the bottom part of the arc in the customview rectangle. I had gone through many stackoverflow questions but its not working. The white area in the canvas need to be removed from the below screenshot. The code for the customview is shown here. Please help me in figuring out the solution for this. Thanks

**Code :**

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    float size = Math.min(getWidth(), getWidth());
    RectF rectRectF = new RectF(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    Path rectPath = new Path();
    rectPath.addRect(rectRectF, Path.Direction.CCW);
    Paint bgPaint = new Paint();
    bgPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    canvas.drawPath(rectPath, bgPaint);
    RectF rectF = new RectF(0, 0, 2 * getWidth(), 2 * getWidth());
    Paint transparentPaint = new Paint();
    transparentPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    transparentPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawArc(rectF, 180, 90, true, transparentPaint);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
 private Canvas bitMapCanvas;
    private Bitmap frameBitmap;
    private Paint paint;
    private PorterDuffXfermode porterDuffXfermode;
     @Override
      protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        // first time setup
        if (bitMapCanvas == null) {
          bitMapCanvas = new Canvas();
          frameBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
          bitMapCanvas.setBitmap(frameBitmap);
     porterDuffXfermode = new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);

        }
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
      }

 @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
.....
....
  paint.setXfermode(porterDuffXfermode);
    bitMapCanvas.drawArc(rectF, 180, 90, true, paint);
canvas.drawBitmap(frameBitmap, 0, 0, null);
  }
```

This can help you. It will clear your color and make it transparent

Comment: I had used this code but when I set the background color for the rect canvas , this code give transparent bg for the arc. But the background color comes to foreground which I don't want to do in the canvas